# How to automate a windows screen that has a webpage embed in it?

Tags: selenium, automation, ui-automation, webautomation

I have a msi installer, which after installation opens up configuration screen. Before I start configuring, I need to enter my login credentials. Now, this login screen opens in a window which has a web page embed to it. I need to automate this login screen to enter the user name and password.

In this below image, it is windows screen. One with red border is a windows pane, inside that is a web page where you can see a fields to enter credentials. When I see this using UISPY, I can see a URL in the 'value' field when pointed inside the pane.

If I use UI automation, it cannot detect the web page. If I use selenium it cannot detect windows screen. How do I handle this scenario. Any suggestion would be of great help.

[image]

Comment: Selenium doesn't have support to access windows component, best bet can be using AutoIt for windows component. VBScript is also a good option as it gives you the control on browser also.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about Selenium by itself and start looking at AutoIT or similar tools, which can operate the native Windows frames and all the possible elements inside. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Just an addition, in fact you can use autoit right from the Selenium: http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/ , but not sure why then you need Selenium :)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium would not be the answer since there would be no available driver. You could use Microsoft's Coded UI to be able to easily automate this.

If it's windows applications I would go with Coded UI, Web applications go with Selenium. (That is my personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

If you are partial to ruby, you could try [rautomation](https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation).  A python alternative would be [pywinauto](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/).